# Difference between single and double precision instructions

Tags: mips, mips32, fpu, mips64

We all know that MIPS FPU has two precisions, single or double. When I looked it in the instruction set, I found for a same operation, the instruction for single precision and double precision have no different.

For example, here from the [MIPS Architecture For Programmers Volume II:](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs316/2007fa/MIPS_Vol2.pdf) , the instruction ADD.fmt [image]

No matter it is double or single precision, the operand and function code are both same. How decoder know it is a single or double precision instruction? Or any hidden information in the 5-bit fmt region? I can not find any good answers from google, can someone explain how this instruction works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MIPS documentation has details on this, under "FPU Operand Format Field". The `fmt` field contains that specific data.

The `fmt` field is 5 bit length and it can take the  following values:

```
0-15: reserved
16: single
17: double
18-19: reserved
20: word
21: long
22-31: reserved
```

Word and Long are *Unimplemented* for ADD.S and ADD.D.

Comment: The fmt region in instruction ADD.fmt is only 5-bit. But in your answer the fmt contains totally 32-bit register. Is that fmt is a seperated register or something? When we implement this instruction, is the hardware of two different precisions same? I mean if a FPU support double precision, then the hardware is for double precision and no matter the instruction is single or double.

Comment: I wrote "possible **values**", not bit positions. 5 bit is 0-31.

Comment: @ShuaiyuJiang I updated the answer to avoid further confusion.